# How to write my own application derived from UdpBasicApp in Omnet++ (inet)?

Tags: omnet++

I want to derive a class from UdpBasicApp of inet in Oment++. Indeed, I want to write my own application. I wrote the following code, but when I compile the project, I have an error. For compiling this project without any error, what should I do?

```
Creating executable: out/clang-release//Manet_1.1.exe
out/clang-release//MyApp.o:(.rdata[_ZTIN4inet11UdpBasicAppE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for inet::ApplicationBase'
out/clang-release//MyApp.o:(.rdata[_ZTV5MyApp]+0x640): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to inet::OperationalBase::handleOperationStage(inet::LifecycleOperation*, int, inet::IDoneCallback*)'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:101: out/clang-release//Manet_1.1.exe] Error 1
```

MyApp.h

```
#include "../../inet/src/inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.h"

using namespace inet;

class  MyApp : public UdpBasicApp
{
public:
};
```

MyApp.c

```
#include "MyApp.h"

Define_Module(MyApp);
```

MyApp.net

```
import inet.applications.udpapp.UdpBasicApp;

simple MyApp extends UdpBasicApp
{
    @class(MyApp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you are working in your own project which does NOT properly link with the INET model. You MUST select INET as a **project reference in your own project's project properties dialog**. That will add INET's include folder to the include path, so you would need to (properly) write only

```
#include "inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.h"
```

instead of

```
#include "../../inet/src/inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.h"
```

And the linker command line would be also modified to link with the INET shared library properly.

Comment: Can you please post a full example? How do the .cc/.h/.ned files look like?